# Import Athena table to Postgres with quotes and commas

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-athena

I have an Athena table in text format. I looks like this in S3:

```
2022-06-05,55389e3b-3730-4cbb-85f2-d6f4de5123f4,{""05b7ede6-c9b7-4919-86d3-015dc5e77d40"":2",""1008b57c-fe53-4e3b-b84e-257eef70ce73"":2",""886e6dce-c40d-4c58-b87d-956b61382f18"":1",""e7c67b9b-3b01-4c3b-8411-f36659600bc3"":9}
2022-06-05,04e5b51e-8e16-4827-80c1-b50776bfb71b,{""04112c3e-0923-4c33-b92e-1183c06580b9"":1",""0f930559-0e66-45c0-bf9e-56edce16448d"":1",""1008b57c-fe53-4e3b-b84e-257eef70ce73"":70",""11e2e1cd-3078-4272-8b8b-55d62d2c0894"":2018",""19109d21-6150-4dd2-82e1-8bc5eee1d55c"":8",""1e58bb5f-cb5b-48d9-b752-f41dd5bd75bc"":32",""28276ff9-5221-4e41-be15-b7f9edee1162"":23",""2b70946f-1004-456b-9786-0c0274d31d1b"":1",""350b04d8-7910-4f19-b14b-d84e046f0bd6"":1",""3d4b0cb7-b701-4086-8fc8-22f957336670"":4",""3ed395b6-b354-4905-8d70-53174d68e293"":1",""41d99562-fd0b-4c1b-9e5b-66b82615b587"":1",""41e778fd-f6b9-4d71-8053-e2f2446b495e"":23",""44760b78-f700-4e4f-bb5b-cfe1de2b3771"":4",""4b01c168-e16d-499c-9e0e-483d7d86f679"":10",""5050d32f-6b4e-493b-bf37-876dc4cf7d4f"":5}
```

The columns are: `DATE`, `UUID`, `JSONB`

I have escaped the `"` and `,` characters, but Postgres seems unable to import it?

```sql
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
  'my_table',
  'd, id, j',
  '(format csv)',
  aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
    'my-bucket',
    'abc/20220608_172519_00015_d684z_740d0f86-1df0-4058-9d2c-7354a328dfcb.gz',
    'us-west-2'
  )
);
```

> ERROR:  extra data after last expected column

Answer (score 0):

JSON should be escaped like this:

```sql
SELECT '"' || replace(json_format(j), '"', '""') || '"' AS escaped_json
FROM my_table
```